# Swift 4 - Decoding JSON which contains period/dot in key

Tags: ios, json, struct, swift4, decodable

I am trying to decode a JSON which contains two keys written using a period/dot prefix (`.ends` and `.starts`). But the decode code throws an error.

My struct looks like this:

```
struct APICallResponse: Codable {
var user: String
var ends: String
var starts: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case user
case ends = ".ends"
case starts = ".starts"
   }
}
```

My decode code:

```
do {
     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
     let dataObject = try decoder.decode(APICallResponse.self, from: data)
} catch {
print("Error"
}
```

My JSON:

```
{
"user": "Mark",
".ends": "2018-10-26T11:30:46.5889685+05:30",
".starts": "2018-10-26T11:33:46.5889685+05:30",
}
```

How can I handle the dot prefix?

Comment: Your code works for me (if I fix the syntax error where you forgot the `)` after the `print`). You have some other problem. Have you tried printing the error thrown by the decoder? That is, `print("Error: \(error)")` in your `catch` clause.

Comment: Yes! The API docs said I should expect Strings, but the call returns Ints. Solved!